# Help with oil sump gasket

Tags: honda, civic, oil-leak

Civic coupe vti 1999.

The oil sump is leaking.  I watched a video and it seems the gasket simply needs to be changed.

1. Could the leak be caused by a deformation of the metal sump itself which and if so could I just hammer itself into place or need a new sump?  Could anything else be causing the leak?
2. When I attempt the repair it could be I have the wrong gasket part or find the sump was damaged in which case I’ll want to stick the old part back on since I don’t have my own garage/workshop. Will it be ok to just bolt the old part back on though I know the leak will still be there?

3. if I do the work outside and the sump is removed for any amount of time might dust and dirt be getting into the engine from below and is this anything to worry about or could I even leave car outside with sump removed for some days without issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it is the sump gasket? Just watching a video is no proof. I have seen aluminium become porous and does not matter how many gaskets you fit it will still leak.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Could the leak be caused by a deformation of the metal sump itself which and if so could I just hammer itself into place or need a new sump? Could anything else be causing the leak?

Yes, most definitely. If you can detect exactly where the leak(s) is/are coming from, and can ensure the leak is off the oil pan, then it's either the pan being out of shape, the gasket going bad, or a combination of both. Until you can absolutely nail it down to being the oil pan gasket (don't assume, ensure that's what it is), don't do any work on the car. By taking the pan off with it not leaking, you'd just be causing yourself extra work.

> 2. When I attempt the repair it could be I have the wrong gasket part or find the sump was damaged in which case I’ll want to stick the old part back on since I don’t have my own garage/workshop. Will it be ok to just bolt the old part back on though I know the leak will still be there?

If you are worried about it leaking, use a Permatex product called *The Right Stuff*. It WILL seal it without issue. It is made to seal on tough jobs.

> 3. if I do the work outside and the sump is removed for any amount of time might dust and dirt be getting into the engine from below and is this anything to worry about or could I even leave car outside with sump removed for some days without issue?

If you need to leave the car sit for a few days, put the sump back on loosely to cover the bottom end of the engine. This is just to cover it up to keep the majority of anything out. Unless you're in a clean room, you're not going to keep all of the contaminants out. This is nothing really to worry about. Any contaminants which get on the engine will just be on the exterior parts of things. Right after start up with fresh oil, the only thing any contaminants will touch is the oil pump, then get trapped in the filter before the oil goes through any working parts of the engine (like bearing journals and what not). Just do your best to keep things clean and it will be fine.

Comment: @Moab - The main bypass is built into the filter, not the housing. It only bypasses when the filter gets too dirty and pressure gets too high within it. Fresh filters won't bypass. A bypass in the filter mount bypasses back into the pan, not into the oil stream. If you'd like to find out more about capture efficiency and how filters work [here is a good website](https://www.machinerylubrication.com/Read/30697/choose-oil-filter). If you have a reference for any of the stats you have, I'm open to them. What you're stating seems foreign to me.

Comment: @Moab - Yes. However, that's not what your comment says and doesn't have much to do with what I'm talking about. Like I said, the bypass in the housing dumps it back to the oil pan, not into the oil system (which would bypass the filter). And on the filter, bypass only happens when the filter is so clogged (or the oil is thick enough) it pushes past the bypass. This won't happen with a new filter and new oil. Most filters are 98%+ efficient, so a little bit of the crap gets through, but not much. Again, not sure where you got your stats on oil bypass percentages.